# OCR-Engine Tesseract: how to automate text recognition on a large amount of files

Tags: perl, parsing, ocr

I have a large amount of files that I want to parse.

they look like these ones: See a example:

http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=134&InterfaceLanguage=&Type=Image

http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=134&InterfaceLanguage=&Type=Html

Well I guess that using Image::OCR::Tesseract could be interesting. I think I parse this with Tesseract ( http://search.cpan.org/~leocharre/Image-OCR-Tesseract-1.24/lib/Image/OCR/Tesseract.pod )

```
use Image::OCR::Tesseract 'get_ocr';

my $image = './hi.jpg';

my $text = get_ocr($image);
```

Is this the proper syntax?

Comment: what is your question exactly? is what you posted working?

Comment: hi Mat i have no experience with OCR - i have made a first trial with tesseract - but i am not sure if i did apply the right code!? I hope to find some with more experience on Tesseract... that supply some help / exprecience - and best practice

Answer (score 0):

You might download and compile the latest version of [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).  Then you can write a (shell or Perl) script to feed all your files for parsing.